# lodash error while building /@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts (1188,142): '(' expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, lodash

Everything was fine, but suddenly my build started to fail. And these are the errors I am seeing

```
ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts (852,68): ';' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts (9,11): ';' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts (9,56): '(' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts (9,72): '(' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts (9,86): '(' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts (9,103): '(' expected.
```

My package.json shows following versions for typescript and lodash:

```
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.74",
"typescript": "2.1.5",
```

I tried to use `npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.1.5` , but that didn't help as npm throws an error saying No compatible version found.

Anyone know what version for lodash I can use?

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error..? Try re-installing it

Comment: It was working fine previously

Comment: I'd try re-installing the module anyway, there shouldn't be any harm, and it might be the culprit

Comment: Still same error after I tried re-installing the module

Answer (score 20):

I fixed this issue by

```
npm install --save @types/lodash@4.14.74
```

npm install alone didn't install that dependency

Comment: I had to follow the instructions here, specifically adding "@types/lodash": "4.14.186"-
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/63022